# Keyboard lags when using UIAlertController

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, uialertview

I have a side project app that uses a UIAlertController with a textbox to get input from the user. My problem is, when a user enters text and presses 'Add', the Keyboard stays open for a good 1-3 seconds before dismissing. However, if the user presses the return key with text entered in the textbox on the keyboard, this does not happen. I originally thought it was from using the completion handlers and having to wait for it to complete, but since using the return key works fine, I don't think that is the case.

This is where I display the alert:

```
func addItem(view: UIViewController, completion: (text: String?) -> Void) {

    let diag = UIAlertController(title: "Add Task", message: "Enter a task name", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    diag.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler({ (textField) -> Void in })

    diag.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Add", style: .Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
        let textOfTask = diag.textFields![0] as UITextField
        let textValue = textOfTask.text!

        if textValue.characters.count > 0 {
            completion(text: textValue)
        }
    }))
    diag.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
    completion(text: nil)
    }))
    view.presentViewController(diag, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

And how I am calling this function is:

```
@IBAction func didPressAdd(sender: AnyObject) {
    addItem(self) {
        (text) in
        if let itemText = text {
            // Check if has all the datas
            if (self.def.objectForKey("simplest_itemlist") != nil) {
                // Does have all the datas
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }

            // Append new data
            self.itemList.append(itemText)
            self.tableView.reloadData()

            // Save to UserDefaults
            self.def.setObject(self.itemList, forKey: "simplest_itemlist")
            self.def.synchronize()

            print(self.itemList)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have dealt with this issue previously. Unfortunately, in all my investigations I have come to the same conclusions as you have. There is now a built-in delay when a button is pressed on the alert. No code that you change or don't run or run on another thread will prevent this delay. Others have also confirmed that this is the functionality built by Apple.

Comment: Wow that is very frustrating..I can't imagine why that would be implemented. Is there a way around this? Can I somehow return the entered text by ONLY using the keyboard return button? I haven't found a way to do that

Comment: I resigned myself to the small delay, recognizing that (1) many people may just use the keyboard done button and (2) users probably won't be bothered by it. If you want to go down the dark road of simulating a user pressing a keyboard button, there lie dragons.

Comment: That's true. I use the keyboard done button almost always if it's available. It just irks me that this exists and if a user does actually use the button, they have to deal with it. Thanks for the info though!

Answer (score 0):

So if I had to take a bet its likely because of the fact that all of this is happening on the main thread, which makes sense if the issue doesn't happen when you hit return without entering anything in. You want your app to be as responsive as possible, so everything user-interaction based and UI based will happen on the main thread. What you probably want to do is asynchronously save the text, which means that any data saving you'll be doing with the inputted text will happen on another thread that isn't dealing with dismissing the alertView. Does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks. It does make sense yes, but the thing is, if I press the return key WITH text entered, everything works fine.

For example: I add text, press 'Add', it lags. Then, I add text and press 'return', it doesn't lag. Is your comment still make sense? Maybe interacting with the alert is the issue?